# How to create subtypes/supertypes in ER Diagrams using Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, data-modeling, erd

I am trying to create ER Diagrams using Oracle SQL Developer's Data Modeler.

I have an entity super type named HOLDING and I have four other subtypes: BOOK, DVD, AUDIO BOOK, and SOFTWARE...

**I am trying to figure out how to get the ER diagram to display the disjoint rule or the overlapping rule and the total specialization or the partial specialization rule.**

For example:

If the question asks me to show that a holding must be exactly on of the subtypes listed then the ER diagram will look like this:[image]

How do I get this to show up in my data modeler? What I have right now is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUBTYPES and SUPERTYPES.

In your sub entity in general tab find Super Type and choose your super entity. And in super entity properties under Subtypes you can define the relation more precisely.

I hope it helped.